# Magento 2 : Change Top Menu Alignment from Vertical to Horizontal

Tags: magento2, menu, navigation

Curerntly top menu navigation show subcategories with images like this:

[image]

How to change default navigation behavior from vertical to horizontal display?

I need to get menu horizontally?